# PHP - Returning values from Google Maps API

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a bit of code I have.

I have a function which is as follows:

```
function getAddressComponent($lat, $lng, $field) {

    $returnValue = '-';
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    if (isset($json['results'])) {

        foreach($json['results'] as $result) {

            foreach ($result['address_components'] as $address_component) {

                $types = $address_component['types'];
                if (in_array($field, $types) && sizeof($types) == 1) {

                    $returnValue = $address_component['short_name'];

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $returnValue;

}
```

I call the function like this:

```
$returnAddress = $this->getAddressComponent( -34.872693, 138.490391, 'administrative_area_level_1' );
```

If i run the function for the administrative_area_level_1 type, it returns nothing, but if i use the $url and enter the lat and lng in the url it returns results for that type... The array looks like so.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "22",
               "short_name" : "22",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Blue-Sails Court",
               "short_name" : "Blue-Sails Ct",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West Lakes",
               "short_name" : "West Lakes",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "South Australia",
               "short_name" : "SA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Australia",
               "short_name" : "AU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "5021",
               "short_name" : "5021",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
```

It returns the `'-'` for the locality and country one as well.

I want it to return a `'-'` if it doesnt exist, but in this case it does exist and its doing my head in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is the condition inside the if:

As you can see in this json that you provided:

```
"types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
```

Its `sizeof/count` is greater than zero, it contains 2.

So when you use the condition:

```
if (in_array($field, $types) && sizeof($types) == 1) { // this fails
// sizeof is not equal to 1
```

So basically, no values are being assigned inside `$returnValue`, thus it just returns your initialization `-`.

Either you just change it to `> 0` or just remove it.